# Expo - LocationTaskService.java NullPointerException on Intent.getExtras()

Tags: android, react-native, expo

Creating an Expo app and have it run a sticky notification, results in a NullPointerException after 15-60 minutes.

Here is the RN code

```
//backgroundTasks.js

import {Permissions} from 'react-native-unimodules';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';
import * as TaskManager from "expo-task-manager";
import {getStore} from "../redux/configureStore";
import {newLocation} from "../redux/actions/device";
import {Log} from "./log";
import {Colors} from "./style/colors";
import * as db from '../utils/db';
import {getTranslator, secondsToInterval} from "./functions";
import {showAlert} from "../redux/actions/app";
import {APP} from "../redux/constants/app";
import {setIgnoreState} from "./state";

export const BG_TRACKING = 'BG_TRACKING';

Log.info(`Unregister all tasks`);
TaskManager.unregisterAllTasksAsync().then(() => {
    Log.info(`Defined new background task ${BG_TRACKING}`);
    TaskManager.defineTask(BG_TRACKING, async ({ data: { locations }, error }) => {
        if(error) {
            Log.error('Error received for locations', error);
        } else {
            locations.forEach(l => getStore().dispatch(newLocation(l)));
        }
    });
});
export const unregister = async () => {
    if(await Location.hasStartedLocationUpdatesAsync(BG_TRACKING)) {
        await Location.stopLocationUpdatesAsync(BG_TRACKING);
    }
};

let permissionIndicationOpen = false;
export const register = async () => {
    let user = getStore().getState().get(APP).get('currentUser');
    if(!user) return;
    let permissionState = await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
    if(!permissionState.granted || permissionState.canAskAgain) {
        if(permissionIndicationOpen) return;
        permissionIndicationOpen = true;
        setIgnoreState(true);
        permissionState = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
        setIgnoreState(false);
        if(permissionState.granted) {
            permissionIndicationOpen = false;
        } else {
            const t = await getTranslator();
            getStore().dispatch(showAlert(t('needPermission'), t('locationPermissionNeeded'), {
                onConfirm: () => {
                    permissionIndicationOpen = false;
                    register()
                }
            }));
        }
    }
    const start = async () => {
        const t = await getTranslator();
        try {
            Log.info(`Registering background task ${BG_TRACKING}`);
            let trackingInterval = await db.getValue('trackingInterval');
            if (!trackingInterval) return;
            let interval = +trackingInterval;
            if (interval < 0) interval = 60 * 60 //every hour, but it will be ignored by the server;
            await unregister();
            await Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync(BG_TRACKING, {
                accuracy: Location.Accuracy.Highest,
                timeInterval: interval * 1000,
                foregroundService: {
                    notificationBody: +trackingInterval > 0 ? t('yourPositionIsBeingMonitored', {
                        period: secondsToInterval(t, interval)
                    }) : t('positionSentOnlyOnAlarm'),
                    notificationColor: Colors.primary
                }
            });
            Log.info(`Successfully registered background task ${BG_TRACKING}`);
        } catch (e) {
            Log.error(`Failed registering background task ${BG_TRACKING}`);
            Log.error(e);
        }
    };
    await start();
};
```

This file is called in the `index.js`, the entry point.

Then I see this stacktrace in Crashlytics.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service expo.modules.location.services.LocationTaskService@97ff6c3 with null: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:4222)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:231)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1984)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7682)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

Comment: Have you figured out a solution to this problem?

Comment: Yes. I've posted the fix

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix

https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/8483

Apparently, changing the return flag of startService to REDELIVER_INTENT fixes it.